# Extension of Bernoulli Cube

Tags: measure-theory, infinite-product

Fundamentally my question is very simple:  does the following argument make sense (it seems counterintuitive to me).

Given an arbitrary set $A$, for any $a \in A$ let $(X_a,B_a,\mu_a)$ be a probability space such that $X_a$ is a locally compact, $\sigma$-compact metric space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B_a$. By the existence of product measures theorem there exists a unique probability measure, $\mu_A$, on $(\Pi_{a \in A}X_a,\Pi_{a \in A}B_a)$ with the condition: 
$$\mu_A\left( \Pi_{a \in A}E_a\right) = \Pi_{a\in A} \mu_a(E_A)$$ 
wherever $E_a\in B_a$ for each $a\in A$ and one has $E_a=X_a$ for all but finitely many $a$.

In particular, let $A = \mathbb{N}$ and each $X_a = \{0,1,2,\dots,a\}$ with the discrete topology, let $B_a$ be the discrete Borel $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. the power set of $X_a$) and $\mu_a$ be the uniform probability measure.

Each $X_{a}$ is compact and therefore locally compact and $\sigma$-compact so there exists a unique probability measure $\mu_{A}$ on $(\Pi_{a = 1}^{\infty}, B_A)$.

The problem for me is that these discrete measures can extend to an infinite product space.

Comment: The $X_a$ don't look compact to me. They look rather like $\mathbb{N}$. But locally compact and $\sigma$-compact they are. However, you write "there exists a unique probability measure $\mu_A$" on the product without giving the condition that uniquely determines the measure. There are a lot of different point masses on that product space.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I should have written a unique probability measure $\mu_A$ with the condition: $\mu_A(\Pi_{a \in A}E_a) = \Pi_{a \in A}\mu_{a}(E_{A})$  wherever $E_a \in B_a$ for each $a \in A$ and one has $E_a = X_a$ for all but finitely many $a$.

Comment: I just noticed "the discrete uniform probability measure". There is no uniform probability measure on an infinite countable space. Did you perhaps mean something like $X_a = \{0,\,1,\,\dotsc,\,a\}$?

Comment: Ah, sorry Daniel. Yes I did mean $X_a = \{0,1,\dots,a\}$